# How to control an embedded vimeo video with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a video on my site

https://clocal.wpengine.com/

that's in a popup box that is obviously only visible when you click on a button to open the popup window. the site is being built on WordPress, and I'm using a WordPress theme called Divi. and I'm using this hack

https://dividezigns.com/pop-up-contact-form-using-divi/

to make my popup window. But here is my problem, everything works, except when I close the popup window the video is still playing in the background. If it were a youtube vid I could use this code

http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/3J2wT/

```
<iframe id="popup-youtube-player" width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/geTgZcHrXTc?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always"></iframe>

$('#stop').on('click', function() {
    //$('#popup-youtube-player').stopVideo();
$('#popup-youtube-player')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');    
});
```

to stop it. but it's a Vimeo video and that code does not work for Vimeo.

I know only a little CSS and HTML and no jQuery or javascript except what I've learned trying to figure this one out, So any help would be great!

thanks.

-sparkie the DOG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's possibly a better solution to my proposed one but could you just clear the `src` value of the video and then reload it at the end of the stop event?

**Code Snippet:**

```
$('#stop').on('click', function() {
   var source = $('#popup-youtube-player').attr('src');

   $('#popup-youtube-player').attr('src','');

   $('#popup-youtube-player').attr('src',source);
});
```

It seems to work in this jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/3J2wT/2325/ (enjoy the cat video)